# Swift 1.2 redeclares Objective-C method

Tags: swift, properties, redeclaration

I just updated  from swift 1.1 to swift 1.2 and get compiler Error:

```
Method 'setVacation' redeclares Objective-C method 'setVacation:'
```

Here some code:

```
var vacation : Vacation?  
func setVacation(_vacation : Vacation)
{...}
```

But I need call `setVacation`

Is any suggestions how fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is cause by the change stated in Xcode 6.3beta release notes:

> Swift now detects discrepancies between overloading and overriding in
>   the Swift type system and the effective behavior seen via the
>   Objective-C runtime. (18391046, 18383574) For example, the following
>   conflict between the Objective-C setter for “property” in a class and
>   the method “setProperty” in its extension is now diagnosed:
>
> ```
>  class A : NSObject {
>      var property: String = "Hello" // note: Objective-C method 'setProperty:’
>                                     // previously declared by setter for
>                                     // 'property’ here
>  }
>  extension A {
>      func setProperty(str: String) { } // error: method ‘setProperty’
>                                        // redeclares Objective-C method
>                                        //'setProperty:’
>  }
> ```

To fix this you need to make all you method signatures unique (as Objective-C does not provide method overload)

Or don't inherit from `NSObject` if you need Swift only class.

Comment: This appears to imply that method overloading is not possible in such classes as UIViewControllers or indeed any class that subclasses any objective-c class.  Is that correct?

Comment: It looks like the clean workaround is to declare these private.  That way the compiler won't try to convert them to ObjC so there won't be a conflict.

Comment: @kwerle Awesome workaround. Didn't think of this before.

Answer (score 4):

Cappy: For the Standford problem I used simply this, because it looks like the Xcode Beta simply says that the operation: (Double, Double) -> Double is the same as operation: Double -> Double, I don't know if it is a bug or not...

But the code below works, but is **NOT** clean :(

```
func performOperation(r:String? = "2", operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    if operandStack.count >= 2 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}

func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double) {
    if operandStack.count >= 1 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Kirsteins, Swift now detects conflicting symbols between Swift and Obj-C, and swift symbols that would cause Obj-C grief.  In addition to the answer given, you can avoid this in general by specifying a required label for the additional types, thus changing the call signature:

```
import Foundation

extension NSObject {
    func foo(d:Double, i:Int) { println("\(d), \(i)") }
    func foo(withInt d:Int, i:Int) { println("\(d), \(i)") }
}

let no = NSObject()
no.foo(withInt:1, i: 2)
```

Beyond that though, and to answer your immediate question, you are trying to apply Obj-C idioms to Swift.  What you really want, is to either implement `didSet` (most likely), or possibly `set`:

```
class WhatIDidLastSummer {

    var vacation:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            // do something
        }
    }

    var staycation:Bool {
        get { return true }
        set {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem but it's not in a setX method. I'm doing the assignment from the iTunesU Stanford Swift course. When I converted to Swift 1.2, some code that used to compile stopped compiling. The method is performOperation.

Comment: 2 methods with different signatures. "func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double)->Double )", and: "func performOperation(operation: (Double)->Double )". The first does not get an error, but the second one does. (The error is: "Method 'performOperation' redeclares Objective-C method 'performOperation:' "). I could see "performOperation" being a genuine ObjC method somewhere... but then why doesn't the first method spawn the error?

Comment: (Without knowing your context), it is because that particular code is either derived from NSObject, or marked as @objc, and Obj-C does not support function / method overloading, even with different type signatures.  TL;DR, it will work just fine in a Swift-only environment, but Obj-C can't use it, and the code is either derived from Obj-C, or made available to Obj-C.

Comment: Specifying a required label for the additional types: Great easy fix. Just add a # sign in front of the argument name to the method that begins with the name "set." e.g. func setCustomerList(#incomingList: CustomerList)