# How to fix Objective C Methods SWIFT

Tags: swift

How would I fix this problem?

Here's the code

```
//
//  TTTImageView.swift
//  TicTacToe
import UIKit

class TTTImageView: UIImageView {

    var player:String?
    var activated:Bool! = false
```

Problem is here and states "Method 'setPlayer' with objective c selector 'setPlayer:'conflicts with setter for 'player'with same objective c selector"

```
   func setPlayer (_player:String){
        self.player = _player

        if activated == false{
            if _player == "x"{
                self.image = UIImage(named: "x")
            }else{
                self.image = UIImage(named: "o")
            }
            activated = true
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried anything yet but will greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

There error is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28500768/3149796

There are lots of great Swift features that you can use instead of what you've got.  Try a property observer (`didSet`) instead of creating a custom setter function.  You can also clean up your code and make it safer with an optional binding (`if let`) and a `where` clause.

Also your `activated` property shouldn't be implicitly unwrapped (`Bool!`), but rather just `Bool`.

```
import UIKit

class TTTImageView: UIImageView {

    var activated: Bool = false

    var player: String? {
        didSet {
            if let player = self.player where self.activated == false {
                if self.player == "x" {
                    self.image = UIImage(named: "x")
                } else {
                    self.image = UIImage(named: "o")
                }
                self.activated = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That Would Not Work Because I Would Need It To Be A func To Carry Out A Command

Comment: Property observers can execute any code that can be executed in a function, and will do so every time you set the player, such as `imageView.player = "x"`.  If you mean you need to execute this image setting code from else where as well, you could create a method called, say, `updatePlayer()` that can be called from the property observer and anywhere else you like.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I was able to fix it by using `@nonobjc`

More information here:
[Swift 2, method 'setOn' with Objective-C selector 'setOn:' conflicts with setter for 'on' with the same Objective-C selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703495/swift-2-method-seton-with-objective-c-selector-seton-conflicts-with-setter#answer-34703891)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

change `setPlayer` to `Player`

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Anish, thanks for your answer, however answers on SO should explain _why_ or _how_ a solution answers the question. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)