# Swift 2, method 'setOn' with Objective-C selector 'setOn:' conflicts with setter for 'on' with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

Swift 2, I have a class inherits from objc's UIView and it has 'on' variable, and related methods 'setOn:animated' and 'setOn:' like below:

```
public class AView: UIView {
var on: Bool = false

public func setOn(on: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    self.on = on
    // do something more about animating
}

public func setOn(on: Bool) {
    setOn(on, animated: false)
}
```

And I got an error message: `method 'setOn' with Objective-C selector 'setOn:' conflicts with setter for 'on' with the same Objective-C selector`

I think `willSet` or `didSet` is not a solution because `setOn:animated:` is called twice even if I add some guard conditions:

```
var on: Bool = false {
    willSet {
        if self.on != newValue {
            setOn(self.on, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
....
....
let a = AView()
a.setOn(true, animated: true) // setOn:animated: is called twice
```

Is there a solution without changing a variable name and methods name?

---

Workaround: My solution is add extra internal variable and expose it with computed property. I don't like adding extra variable and definitely there will be a better solution.

```
private var isOn: Bool = false
var on: Bool {
    set(newOn) {
        setOn(newOn, animated: false)
    }
    get {
        return isOn
    }
}

public func setOn(on: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    self.isOn = on
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: Make it `setOn(isOn on: Bool) ...` instead?

Comment: @JavaNut13 It works. But, need extra named parameter. I want to keep both a vriable and method name. I can avoid this issue by adding extra variable but I want to know is there a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similarly as in [Compiler error: Method with Objective-C selector conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457720/compiler-error-method-with-objective-c-selector-conflicts-with-previous-declara/31500740#31500740), you can also hide *properties* from 
the Objective-C runtime with `@nonobjc`:

```
public class AView: UIView {
    @nonobjc var on: Bool = false

    public func setOn(on: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        self.on = on
        // do something more about animating
    }

    public func setOn(on: Bool) {
        setOn(on, animated: false)
    }
}
```

which prevents a conflicting Objective-C setter from being auto-generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then do I have to provide `isOn`(getter for on) to access this property in Objective C?

Comment: @ccoroom: If you want to access the property from Objective-C as well then your solution with a `private var isOn` is probably the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `willSet` you need to use `didSet`

```
var on: Bool = false
{
    didSet
   {
        if self.on != oldValue
        {
            setOn(self.on, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'didSet' has no difference. setOn:animated: called twice.

Comment: @ccoroom: Check the if condition I'm using, did you tried the same code ? Is the same issue happening ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Because I called `a.setOn(true, animated: true)` and `self.on = on` is inside `setOn:animated:`. the oldValue is false, so calls `setOn:animated:` once more.